# Gnuplot 4.6 xtics label disappear

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I decided to migrate to the latest version of gnuplot from 4.4 to 4.6
I am having issue with the x label disappearing with version 4.6 but being there with version 4.4.

here is a stripped down version of my script.

```
set key outside
set title "MY TITLE"
set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%m/%d %H:%M"
set xdata time
set ylabel "Y LABEL"
set xlabel "Time"
set grid
set xtics rotate by 90 offset 0,-5
set terminal pngcairo size 1000,500 font ",9"
set xtics font ",8.0"
set ytics font ",8.0"
set output 'test.png'
plot '-' using 1:2 with linespoints ti "legend"
01/01/2013-00:15 186557
01/01/2013-01:15 254654
01/01/2013-04:00 180146
01/01/2013-06:15 191059
e
set key inside
```

I've identified the issue to this line

```
set xtics rotate by 90 offset 0,-5
```

Because my label is too long the offset makes it go away

if you remove the offset to

```
set xtics rotate by 90
```

Not the label show but in the middle of the chart.

Version 4.4 used to compress the chart to leave room for the label.

I guess my knowledge to gnuplot is limited.
Anyone has an idea?

thanks

Comment: As an aside, I submitted a bug report.  We'll see if Ethan (or one of the other gnuplot devs agrees that it's a bug -- My last 2 reports have been closed as non-bugs ;).  You can follow the progress [here](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3599407&group_id=2055&atid=102055)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**, courtesy of Ethan Merritt

A better way to do this is to change the justification of the labels to being right justified (rather than the default centered).

```
set xtics rotate by 90 right
```

This correctly calculates the margin without needing to hardcode a margin size

---

The label placement here seems a little flaky to me.  I think there might be a bug which I'll probably report.  One workaround is to explicitly set the location of the "x-axis" via:

```
set bmargin at screen 0.2
```

The reason it seems flakey is because with `set bmargin at screen 0.2`, the xtic labels clearly extend higher than the position of the xlabel.  However, if you comment that line out, all of a sudden they don't extend higher than the position of the xlabel.

Here are the plots with and without that line:

[image]

[image]

Perhaps cairo/pango cut out labels where any portion of the label extends past the visible "canvas" area?

As a side note, the plot also seems to be roughly correct if I use the `postscript` terminal...

Comment: Thank a lot for your help, i will give it try and report.

Comment: That first line did the trick.
The second one removed the x label somehow.
I'll just use the first one.

Comment: Using "set xtics rotate by 90 right" makes things even worse for me, as it clips one extra character off the xtics.  This is with Gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0, with the png terminal.

Comment: And using "set bmargin at screen 0.2" adds a very large white strip below the xtics.